# UI is getting mix up on back button press

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragment

I have FragmentActivity (MainFragmentActivity) that is calling some fragments. I will say the below one is the 3rd Fragment.

```
BaseFragment fragSensors = SensorsPagerFragment.newInstance(
                            m_objAppCredentials);
FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

if (bFirst)
    ft.add(R.id.flControlContainer, fragSensors, strTag);
else
    ft.replace(R.id.flControlContainer, fragSensors, strTag);
```

And below class holds a viewpaper which calls more fragment upon swipe.
And in that one of the fragment an activity is called. 
When the back button is pressed from the activity. The 1st Fragment UI appears and its mixes with UI of one of the fragment in the viewpager.

How to destroy the UI of the fragment inside the viewpaper or to avoid UI mixing?

```
public class SensorsPagerFragment extends BaseFragment {
    ViewPager m_oVP;

    public SensorsPagerFragment() {
        LogUtils.LOGD("DEBUG", "SensorsPagerFragment::CTOR");
    }

    public static SensorsPagerFragment newInstance(AppCredentials objAppCredentials) {
        SensorsPagerFragment frag = new SensorsPagerFragment();
        m_objAppCredentials = objAppCredentials;
        return frag;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sensors_pager, container, false);

        m_oVP = (ViewPager) v.findViewById(R.id.vpSensors);
        //pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(0);
        // Attach the adaptor to the PAGER
        m_oVP.setAdapter(buildAdapter());

        return v;
    }

    private PagerAdapter buildAdapter() {
        return (new SensorFragmentPA(getChildFragmentManager()));
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        CustomToast.Warning(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                "SensorsPagerFragment::onStop()", 1);
    }

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // class SensorFragmentPA
    class SensorFragmentPA extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SensorFragmentPA(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return Constants.cTOTAL_PAGES;
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int nPageNum) {
            SensorsFragment f = SensorsFragment.newInstance(m_objAppCredentials, nPageNum);
            return f;
        }

        @Override
        public String getPageTitle(int nPageNum) {
            return Integer.toString(nPageNum + 1);
        }

        @Override
        public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
            super.destroyItem(container, position, object);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the issue.

I have implemented the callbacks in each fragment. And in the MainFragmentActivity replace the fragments.